# how to solve "user.getIdToken() is not a function" error coming from a file I didn't create

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, svelte

So I have a simple project with sveltefire (svelte + firebase). I can sign in, I can sign out and I can create an account. In the component to create an account, I have these lines of code:

```
        let ActionCodeSettings = {url: 'https://www.Verify.com/?email=' + email };
        await sendEmailVerification(email, ActionCodeSettings).then();
        let result = getRedirectResult(auth);
```

However, I am getting an error from a file called "email.ts". I did not create this file, but it gives me:

```
 uncaught error in promise user.getIdToken() is not a function.
```

I put the lines to send an email verification before I create the user, since I don't want to have a false user. and it should be sending it since I just inputted the email. Is it that the problem? if so, is there a work around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the documentation of the [`sendEmailVerification` function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth#sendemailverification) it expects a `User` object as its first argument, while it seems that you are passing in a email address.

You'll need to pass in a `User` object, for example as shown in the documentation on [sending a user verification email](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#web-version-9_6):

```
mport { getAuth, sendEmailVerification } from "firebase/auth";

const auth = getAuth();
sendEmailVerification(auth.currentUser)
  .then(() => {
    // Email verification sent!
    // ...
  });
```